# Count number of queries per page request?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli

I need to know how many sql queries are being executed per page request. As the site is already done and I am just running optimization analysis, I would prefer if any solution offered doesnt require that i change the entire website structure.

I use a single connection to send all queries to the MySQL database:

```
define('DATABASE_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
define('DATABASE_NAME', 'foco');
define('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DATABASE_PASSWORD', '');

$DB_CONNECTION = new mysqli(
    DATABASE_SERVER,
    DATABASE_USERNAME,
    DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    DATABASE_NAME,
    3306
);
```

Then to execute a query i use:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sometable`";
$queryRun = $DB_CONNECTION->query($query);
```

Is there a way to count how many queries have been sent and log the answer in a text file just before php closes the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the mysqli object and override the query method:

```
class logging_mysqli extends mysqli {
    public $count = 0;
    public function query($sql) {
        $this->count++;
        return parent::query($sql);
    }
}

$DB_CONNECTION = new logging_mysqli(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways would be to run a log function inside your `$DB_CONNECTION->query()`.

That way you can either log each individual query to a db table, or perform basic test on query speed and then store this, or just increment the count (for number of queries) and store this.

Comment: How do I do that? The query() function is part of the MySQLi class.

Comment: The below answer by @Sjoerd has that all sorted for you. Go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Create class extending `mysqli`, make $DB_CONNECTION object of that class and do your statistics in your implementation of `query()` method. Eventually it shall call `parent::query()` to do real job.

Answer (score 0):

Create a proxy that you use instead of mysqli directly...

```
class DatabaseCounter {
    private $querycount = 0;
    private $mysqli = null;

    // create mysqli in here in constructor


    public function query(...) {
        $this->queryCount++;
        $this->mysqli->query(...);
    }
}

$DB_CONNECTION = new DatabaseCounter();
```